# What are the central institutes that take care of Arctic research?

Tags: sea-ice

I am currently looking for data for a thesis. I wanted to ask which marine research institutes outside the European Union (USA, Canada, China, etc.) deal with the Arctic and/or the AMOC.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but try NSIDC in the USA.

Comment: here is a site monitoring the ice on greenland http://polarportal.dk/en/home/ and a link to http://nsidc.org/arcticseaicenews/